# Functionality of libflang `sect` calls

Tags: fortran, flang

I was looking at the perf profile for one of the spec2017 benchmark compiled with llvm. I saw hotness in few of the libflang routines. But I am not able to figure out what is the functionality of **f90_sect_i8** function. I searched for sect calls but could not find anything substantial.

Comment: What context does it appear in?

Comment: Did you check the source code for libflang?  It is available on-line.

Comment: @evets: Yes I did check the source code for libflang, but couldn't figure out these calls.